# How to paint the different rows in ngFor Angular 5

Tags: angular, html-table, bootstrap-4, angular5, ngfor

I'm creating a table which has some rows loaded from `*ngFor`:

```html
    <tr *ngFor="let car of cars">
      <td>{{car?.id}}</td>
      <td>{{car?.date | date : "short"}}</td>
      <div [ngSwitch]="car?.state">
          <td *ngSwitchCase=1 class="col">Sold</td>
          <td *ngSwitchCase=7 class="col">Repaired</td>
          <td *ngSwitchDefault class="col">Out of stock</td>
      </div>
    </tr>
```

And I want each row to be painted with different color, it will depend on the car state. I know how to do it with static content but not if it comes from a database and I have to load it with the `*ngFor` directive.

As I'm using bootstrap I'd like to use the class style .table-success for state 1, .table-info for state 7 and primary for default.

```html
<tr class="table-success">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, a `<div>` inside a `<tr>` is not going to work, a `<ng-container>` will suit your needs here. This is a special tag only used within the angular compiler, which will transform into a HTML comment.

Besides that, you are missing some double quotes for your `*ngSwitchCase`.

About the classes, you can use the `[class.class-name]` binding or `[ngClass]` if you think that's more structured:

```html
<tr *ngFor="let car of cars" class="table-primary" 
    [class.table-success]="car.state === 1"  [class.table-info]="car.state === 7">
  <td>{{car?.id}}</td>
  <td>{{car?.date | date : "short"}}</td>
  <ng-container [ngSwitch]="car?.state">
      <td *ngSwitchCase="1" class="col">Sold</td>
      <td *ngSwitchCase="7" class="col">Repaired</td>
      <td *ngSwitchDefault class="col">Out of stock</td>
  </ng-container>
</tr>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Write styles with your requirement with the possible car state names.

let us take . If you get car status delivered.

then write

```css
.delivered{
  background: green,
  color: black
 }
```

```html
<tr [ngClass]="{{car.status}}" *ngFor="let car of cars">
  <td>{{car?.id}}</td>
  <td>{{car?.date | date : "short"}}</td>
  <div [ngSwitch]="car?.state">
      <td *ngSwitchCase=1 class="col">Sold</td>
      <td *ngSwitchCase=7 class="col">Repaired</td>
      <td *ngSwitchDefault class="col">Out of stock</td>
  </div>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the `ngClass` directive:

```
[ngClass]="{'table-success' : car.state == 1}"
```

Since you have multiple options and it might be a bit hard to read you can add a method in the component .ts file

```
[ngClass]="getClasses(value)"
```

And create a method getClasses that returns the proper class for the item.

But in the end if you already have a switch why don't you just do that:

```html
 <td *ngSwitchCase="1" class=".table-success col">Sold</td>
 <td *ngSwitchCase="7" class=".table-info col">Repaired</td>
 <td *ngSwitchDefault class="col">Out of stock</td>
```

add the classes to the switch you already hav e:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngClass`.
In the table row:

```html
<tr [ngClass]="{'table-success': (car?.state=='1'), 'table-info': (car?.state=='7'), 'primary': (car?.state=='7' && car?.state=='1')}" *ngFor="let car of cars">
```